# Django Foreign Key: get related model?

Tags: python, django, django-models, foreign-keys

Is it possible to get the related model of a foreign key through the foreign key field itself?

For example, if I have 3 models:

```
class ModelA(models.Model)
    field1 = models.CharField(max_length=10)

class ModelB(models.Model)
    field1 = models.CharField(max_length=10)

class ModelC(models.Model)
    field1 = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    field2 = models.ForeignKey(ModelA)
    field3 = models.ForeignKey(ModelB)
```

and I want to do:

```
for field in ModelC._meta.fields:
    if field.get_internal_type() == "ForeignKey":
        #get the related model for field e.g. ModelA or ModelB
```

Is this possible using just the models themselves rather than instances of the models?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

If ModelA has an FK field named "foo", then this is how you can get the related model:

```
ModelA._meta.get_field('foo').rel.to
```

With your code, it would look like:

```
for field in ModelC._meta.fields:
    if field.get_internal_type() == "ForeignKey":
        print field.rel.to
```

If found it out by using tab completion in the shell long ago, it still works. You might want to learn to use the shell to reverse engineer stuff like that.

### Update for Django>=2.0 users

Syntax has changed. Use the below code to get the related model:

```py
ModelA._meta.get_field('foo').related_model
```

Comment: Update: In newly released Django 2.0, it looks like "rel" is no longer a field of ForeignKey. You could try:  `ModelA._meta.get_field('foo').related_model`. I figure this out by typing "tab" to auto-complete in command line.

Answer (score 1):

When trying to extract relations like this, I use a lot of command-line experimentation. A common pattern I use is `_=starting_point.<chained_attributes>;pprint((_, dir(_)))`. For example:

```
_=ModelC;pprint((_, dir(_)))
_=ModelC.field2;pprint((_, dir(_)))
_=ModelC.field2.field;pprint((_, dir(_)))
_=ModelC.field2.field.rel;pprint((_, dir(_)))
_=ModelC.field2.field.rel.to;pprint((_, dir(_)))
```

(You'll need to do `from pprint import pprint` first, naturally.) That lets me experiment with adding / removing attributes until a find the item I want... while seeing clearly what I've got and what's available at the next level down. From this, I get
`ModelC.field2.field.rel.to == ModelA`. The same base pattern can be used to explore reverse relationships, many-to-many relationships, starting with an instance rather than the class, etc.