# How to iterate over every foreign key in a model?

Tags: django

If I have a model like the following:

```
class Keyword(models.Model):
    model1 = models.ForeignKey(Model1, null=True, blank=True, default=None)
    model2 = models.ForeignKey(Model2, null=True, blank=True, default=None)
    model3 = models.ForeignKey(Model3, null=True, blank=True, default=None)
    model4 = models.ForeignKey(Model4, null=True, blank=True, default=None)      
    not_foreign_key = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=True, blank=True)
```

How can I iterate over each foreign key?

I'm imagining some sort of for loop like this (pseudocode):

```
for each foreign key in Keyword:
    do something with the foreign key
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django Foreign Key: get related model?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10347210/django-foreign-key-get-related-model)

Comment: Do you want to iterate of the field descriptions or do you want to access all foreign key fields of a model instance?

Comment: @ozgur Yes, that's basically it, thanks. Something like: for field in Keyword._meta.fields:
    if field.get_internal_type() == "ForeignKey": ...

Comment: One follow up question please: What if Model1 wanted to find out which models have a foreign key to it? Basically a query on Model1 which would return a Keyword instance, because Keyword has a foreign key to Model1...

Comment: @TomBrock See my answer below. Just call it with (Forward=False, Reverse=True)

Comment: @Sebastian Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the private API to get all foreign key information:

```
# 'instance' is an instance of any kind of Django model
fields = instance._meta._get_fields(forward=True, reverse=False)
for field in fields:
   obj_field_value = field.value_from_obj(instance)  # This is the value the instance has for this field
   foreign_key_related_model = field.related_model  # returns the model the foreign key links to. There are plenty more properties here
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I will spend some time digesting what you wrote.

Comment: It's recommended by Django to use the public method `get_fields()` (instead of `_get_fields()`) https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/meta/#django.db.models.options.Options.get_fields

Comment: @Risadinha Good luck supplying parameters 'forward' and 'reverse' to the public function. I couldn't get it to work without using the private API.

Comment: You're right, those parameters are not available. But they are not necessary for this problem. The return value of the `get_fields()` method seems to be cached so there might be performance implications which of those methods you use. Also, I think it's good to be aware of the official method in this context.